# What is saved by spark Autoloader checkpoint?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, databricks-autoloader

I have the following code I wish to use for copying data arriving in a folder on a regular basis:

```
val streamingQuery = spark.readStream
.format("cloudFiles")
.option("cloudFiles.format", "binaryFile")
.schema("`path` STRING, `modificationTime` TIMESTAMP, `length` BIGINT, `content` BINARY")
.option("recursiveFileLookup", "true")
.load("my path here")
.filter(col("modificationTime") > "2023-10-30 07:00:00")
.writeStream
.trigger(Trigger.AvailableNow())
.foreachBatch (my code goes here on how I copy files)
.option("checkpointLocation", "my path here")
.start()
.awaitTermination()
```

The question I have is that in my case what will be actually saved by the checkpoint? Everything that has been read from the folder or only those files, that are filtered by modification time? The reason I am asking is because I would like spark to evade trying to read all of the files in the folder - which is why I would like to have a checkpoint - however I would not want to copy all files before modification date as they are not needed.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not including!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this approach, it will scan all files anyway, and Spark will do filtering.  It's better to use the `modifiedAfter` option of Databricks Autoloader ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/options)) to specify the cutoff timestamp - then filtering will be done during file scanning.

P.S. Another thing that can help with performance is to use the [file notification mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/options#file-notification-options) instead of the default directory listing mode. Still, it may require additional permissions on the storage account.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! I find it difficult to find the proper documentations on this topic, so this helps a lot.

Comment: Please let me ask another question:
If Autoloader starts streaming data from the specified folder, and is given the `modifiedAfter` option as you have said and also has an `availableNow( )` trigger, will it stop reading files with modification time equal to the time the job had been started, or will it try to read in new files that arrived in the folder after the job had been started?   

So essentially, there are so many files in my folder already with quite a big amount of new files regularly arriving that I am afraid it will never catch up.

Comment: that may depend on the mode. For big number of files, I would recommend to use "file notification" mode instead of directory listing mode that is default